# Racing condition examples

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, cpu, race-condition, cpu-architecture

What are some of the practical examples of racing condition in hardware and software?
Example should not be about a code explaining what a race condition is but a situation in a system.

For example - When two music players are trying to access the speaker.

Comment: Regarding your edit I also edited my answer. I hope it's more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very good explanation with a simple example at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317723/description-of-race-conditions-and-deadlocks

I will quote the most important part (which to be honest is almost the complete article).

> Visual Basic code:
>
> ```
>    'Thread 1
>    Total = Total + val1
>    'Thread 2
>    Total = Total - val2
> ```
>
> Assembly code (with line numbers) from the compilation of the
>   preceding Visual Basic code:
>
> ```
> 'Thread 1
>  1.   mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[031B49DCh] 
>  2.   add         eax,edi 
>  3.   jno         00000033 
>  4.   xor         ecx,ecx 
>  5.   call        7611097F 
>  6.   mov         dword ptr ds:[031B49DCh],eax 
>  'Thread 2
>  1.   mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[031B49DCh] 
>  2.   sub         eax,edi 
>  3.   jno         00000033 
>  4.   xor         ecx,ecx 
>  5.   call        76110BE7 
>  6.   mov         dword ptr ds:[031B49DCh],eax
> ```
>
> By looking at the assembly code, you can see how many operations the
>   processor is performing at the lower level to execute a simple
>   addition calculation. A thread may be able to execute all or part of
>   its assembly code during its time on the processor. Now look at how a
>   race condition occurs from this code.
>
> Total is 100, val1 is 50, and val2 is 15. Thread 1 gets an opportunity
>   to execute but only completes steps 1 through 3. This means that
>   Thread 1 read the variable and completed the addition. Thread 1 is now
>   just waiting to write out its new value of 150. After Thread 1 is
>   stopped, Thread 2 gets to execute completely. This means that it has
>   written the value that it calculated (85) out to the variable Total.
>   Finally, Thread 1 regains control and finishes execution. It writes
>   out its value (150). Therefore, when Thread 1 is finished, the value
>   of Total is now 150 instead of 85.

EDIT: Please someone correct me if I'm wrong here.

I've seen you've edited your question to specify your doubt so I'll extend my answer accordingly. In reality having two music players trying to access the speaker to output sound is probably not that different as having two threads trying to write to `stdout`. There is a common buffer to which data is sent which is then processed by (in the case of the speaker) the driver. The consequences of the `stdout` example is that the characters can be interleaved and in the speaker the same would occur: the sounds would be interleaved, since it can't play both simultaneously. Therefore the race condition consequences also apply to a "system situation".

Comment: `stdio` functions use locking, so the characters from one `printf` can't mix with (or overwrite) characters from an `fwrite` in another thread or whatever.  But two separate `printf` calls aren't guaranteed to be contiguous.

Comment: related: [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/can-num-be-atomic-for-int-num) has more about an atomic increment vs. separate load / increment / store.

Comment: @Peter Cordes I didn't know that and I apreciate your comment. I based my stdout example from here http://www.minek.com/files/unix_examples/race.html where you can actually see output being interleaved, but that's because they are writing a char at a time (which was what I had in mind in my answer)

Comment: The reason `putc` is slow (and that it would be silly to ever use it that way) is that it has to lock/unlock stdio, otherwise multiple threads could *overwrite* each other's data in the output buffer, or even corrupt the data structures.  getc/putc_unlocked exist to allow fast char-at-a-time I/O  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/getc_unlocked.html, but of course can't be used from multiple threads at once.  Anyway, yes, in that example `putc` in one thread races with `putc` in the other thread to acquire the lock every time one thread releases it.

Comment: Possibly when stdout is unbuffered, there's no locking inside the stdio code, and they end up just making `write` system calls directly.  In that case, the threads race with each other inside the kernel, to see which one's `write()` system call appears first for that file descriptor (with its associated file position tracked by the kernel).